# C# error. The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, node.js, tls1.2

I have created c# .Net client and a node js server. I am getting fwg error **after I shifted my node project to a new Ubuntu server**.

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll
Exception caught: System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

The client is working fine with the earlier server.
The certificate is self signed and I have used certificate error bypass method:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

Which works fine with the earlier server.
I have also tried following methods in the client:

```
 ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
         new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(
              delegate
              { return true; }
          );
```

```
 ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

```
 ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
```

```
 ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

```
 ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.ssl3;
```

I am able to access the seerver on https using a normal browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

And ensure your are using HTTPS in the url.
Otherwise, try to use just HTTP in the url.

Good Luck!

Comment: I've tired this, not working. I suppose it has got something to do at the server end coz that is the only thing which has changed in the complete setup.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I replaced the `HttpWebRequest` method with `WebClient` and it worked.
I'm still not sure why the earlier was not working, moreover it was working for one server but not other. 
Strange.
Anyways, I got it working now.